# jQuery UI .sortable .on click move items and also keep sorting functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a working code that on click moves item from 2 lists back and forth.
However this breaks the sorting functionality.

I want to be able to use the click but also be able to sort the item by dragging them if necessary and avoid to fire the .on click in this case.

what should I do?

FIddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/72RTz/365/

HTML:

```
 <h5 class="prefix-popover-heading">Group 1</h5>
           <!-- IF .prefix_option or .prefix_used -->
            <ul id="available_prefixes" class="prefixed_sortable list-inline">
        <!-- <li id="disable-selection">{L_PREFIX_BASKET}</li> -->
             <li class="click_area">item1</li>
      <li class="click_area">item2</li>
    <li class="click_area">item3</li>
            </ul>

  <h5 class="prefix-popover-heading">Group 2</h5>
<div class="group2">
<div id="PrefixBtn" class="input-group-addon fade">
    <ul id="used_prefixes" class="prefixed_sortable">
      <!-- <li class="placeholder">Drop here</li> -->
         <li class="click_area">item4</li>
      <li class="click_area">item5</li>
    <li class="click_area">item6</li>

    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Make divs sortable
    $("#available_prefixes, #used_prefixes").sortable({
        connectWith: '.prefixed_sortable',
        items: 'li',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        placeholder: 'ui-sortable-placeholder',
        tolerance: 'pointer',
}).disableSelection()
//  lets make it easier and append item on click as well
  .on('click', '.click_area', function(){
            $(this).appendTo($("#available_prefixes, #used_prefixes").not($(this).closest("ul")));
    });
```

UPDATE:
apparently this is a problem only under FIREFOX. Under CHROME works as intended. How do I fix it?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is? I can click to move the items and the sorting functionality still works.

Comment: try releasing the click... it goes back to the list... that's not the intended behavior if you are sorting it. The intended behavior should be : click to move back and fort and if I hold the click then act as default sorting therefore drag, drop and sort.. See what I mean?

Comment: If I let go of an item and it is still within its original group, I expect it to go back, which it does. If I let go of an item in the adjacent group, it is correctly added to the other group, which is also expected behaviour.

Comment: oh this is so odd. that's the correct behavior but only under CHROME. Try Firefox. it's not correct. Hows this even possible? how can they interpret the code in two ways?  How do I fix it ? :-/

Comment: Yep. It's definitely broken in FireFox. Not sure what the problem is without some investigation.

Comment: No idea what to do. Super surprised nothing about this on the net. Jquery UI bug or FireFox bug? I just want to get it to work :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears in FireFox because the `click` event is handled differently. I have no idea why that is the case, but the functionality you want will work if you change the `click` event to a `mouseup` event. It's okay to use the `mouseup` event in your context and it won't cause items to move if the event occurs outside the "sortable" area.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/72RTz/368/)

Comment: that doesn't work in Chrome though :-/ It keeps the drag and its stuck.